# eCommerce systems with demo

Tags: e-commerce, web-applications, demo

I want to try some eCommerce systems to take look of how they implement the diffentent aspects

- Items publication
- Stock
- Sells
- Return
- Etc, Etc

I'm developing a system myself (web application writen in PHP) and I have the feeling than I'm over complicating the process in several parts (particularly in the relations between products and stock loading)
I found and tried some systems but in all the cases the demos/free account are very basic and don't cover the areas I want to look at.

The systems can be writen in any platform, I only want to take ideas from the interface, not to look at the code.

Before someone says it's a subjective question. I'll accept the first answer that can give me a clue with the products relationships.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: I need to see how to present those complicated aspects to the user in an easy to understand way.  
Example of a complecated part: when the store gets a cargo from the provider, the operator has to look at every item on the bill and compare it with the article loaded in the base to check for charges in the price, then him has to create an order to load the item via a barcode reader, but, in many cases, there is no barcode, so the operator has to open a different order to print the barcode...

Comment: Other problem: relationships. One item in particular has many variations (color, size, etc) and every variation has his own stock. So if lets say the operatos is creating the article "Acme t-shit" with 3 colors and 5 possible sizes. He must create 3*5=15 articles for the variations plus one more as parent of the variations...

Comment: One more: one product selled by more than one provider, the item is exactly the same, but the cost vary (wildly in some cases), the providers have different commercial conditions and different delivery times. I have to take this and present only one product to the final user... also I have to guide the operator to the best buy when he is ordering reposition.

Answer (score 1):

If it's the interface you are concerned with, then looking at existing software is not a good idea. They're one crappier than the other. Seriously, they suck.

It is better to educate yourself about good UI design from the works of professional UI designers and usability experts. For example, useit.org

Comment: You are right. But let me give a little credit to humanity. There must be at least one with a good ui. There must be one leading by example.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the following:

- http://lemonstandapp.com/demo/
- http://www.magentocommerce.com/demo
- http://www.cs-cart.com/demo-item.html

Answer (score 0):

http://php.opensourcecms.com/scripts/show.php?catid=3&category=eCommerce

They have a selection of (open source) ecommerce demos running you can check out.

Answer (score 0):

In the Rails space, I'd suggest two popular engines for purely admin interfaces:

- ActiveAdmin: http://activeadmin.info/
- RailsAdmin: https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin

I believe ActiveAdmin has a nice demo which shows examples of how it would be implemented in an ecommerce app. RailsAdmin has a nice demo, but it's not specific to ecommerce.

Also, a few Rails solutions to check out:

- [Spree](http://spreecommerce.com/)
- [ror-e](http://www.ror-e.com/)
- [Piggybak](http://www.piggybak.org/)

Admittedly, I've been involved in development in both Spree and Piggybak, and Ror-e was derived from Spree. So you may see some commonalities between them. And [here](http://blog.endpoint.com/2009/12/rails-ecommerce-product-optioning-in.html) is another resource that describes the product data model in Spree.

Comment: Not to sound critical but ror-e was created because of the frustration I had from Spree.  (as opposed to derived from)  I tried to take what I learned from spree and make a better project.  Spree tries to be a "framework" and ror-e tries to give you a rails app with all the e-commerce functionality out of the box.

Comment: I think you are arguing over semantics here. The word "derive", translated loosely, can mean to trace from a source or origin, which is what I see it as because the work on it came from your experiences with Spree. It most certainly improves upon certain aspects. My original use of the word "derive" was not meant to undervalue the improved aspects of ror-e.

Comment: Yeah I didn't mean to sound too critical.  Sorry